# Getting wrong column default value

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL, I have created a table called `categories` with a `trending` and a `status` column, both are set to have a default value of 0:

![the structure of the table categories in xampp mysql][1]

But when I insert a new record, the columns are set to 1, no matter if I give a value or not.

After the insert:
![the data in the table categories where none of trending and status field is selected even though showing 1 values for both trending and status][2]

Can anyone help me out to solve this error?

-code to push the data in the database is given below:

```
<div class="card card-outline card-info">  
   <div class="card-header">  
     <h4>  
        New Category
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md
        float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal- 
        default"> 
          ADD
        </button>
     </h4>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body"></div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-default">  
   <div class="modal-dialog">  
      <div class="modal-content">  
         <div class="modal-header">  
              <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Category</h4>  
              <button type="button" class="close" data- 
              dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">  
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
         </div>
         <form action="code.php" method="POST" id="cat_form">  
             <div class="modal-body">  
                 <div class="form-group">  
                    <label for="">Category Name</label>  
                    <input type="text" name="name"class="form- 
                    control" required>  
                 </div>  
                 <div class="form-group">  
                    <label for="">Description</label>  
                    <textarea name="description" class="form- 
                    control" required rows="5">  
                    </textarea>  
                 </div>  
                 <div class="form-group">  
                    <label for="">Trending</label>  
                    <input type="checkbox" name="trending">Trending
                 </div>  
                 <div class="form-group">  
                    <label for="">Status</label>  
                    <input type="checkbox"name="status">Status 
                 </div>
             </div>  
             <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                  <button type="submit" name="category_save" 
                  class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>  
             </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

-code for submit button:

```
if (isset($_POST['category_save']))  
{  
    $name = $_POST['name'];  
    $description = $_POST['description'];  
    $trending = $_POST['trending'] = true ? '1':'0';  
    $status = $_POST['status'] = true ? '1':'0';  
    
    $category_query = "INSERT INTO categories 
    (name,description,trending,status) VALUES 
    ('$name','$description','$trending','$status')"; 
    $cate_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $category_query);  
    if ($cate_query_run)  
    {  
       echo "<script>  
           alert(' - Category Inserted  Succesfully!'); 
           window.location.href='category.php';  
       </script>";  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        echo "<script>  
           alert(' - Category Insertion Failed!'); 
           window.location.href='category.php';  
        </script>";  
    }  
}
```

table structure before data insertion
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEX7H.png

table after data insertion
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPfmo.png

thanks in advance

Comment: try with adding default 0 inside both column

Comment: In my humble opinion, it's difficult to be able to help you without knowing how you achieve your integration. Because you want that if the field (for example) "trending" is not filled in, its value in the base is "0"...? This is what you want..?

Comment: _"but when i insert the new record"_ - and how _exactly_ are you doing that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, okay, great understanding of the word "exactly" you are showing there ... Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit this to make it into a question that contains a proper amount of relevant information.

Comment: @Juan, yes that is what i exactly wanted

Comment: With this code `$trending = $_POST['trending'] = true? '1':'0';` What do you expect...? Because the data retrieved in POST are not booleans...

Comment: @Juan, I wish that if the both trending and status checkboxes are checked or if either one of them is check then it should return value 1 . if not checked it should return value  0 .

Comment: Have you tested to display what the `$_POST['trending']` variable contains...? In my opinion, it contains neither "true" nor "false" depending on whether the box is checked. But have you tested...?

Comment: And if you want your checkboxes to return "1" if checked why not put a "1" value in your checkboxes already....? With this code `<input type='checkbox' value='1'>`

Comment: @Juan, yes I have tested  $_POST['trending'].it is always giving me the value "1" whether the checkbox of trending is checked or not.same is the case with $_POST['status'].

Comment: Did you see my answer...? And my proposal for managing checkboxes...?

Comment: @Juan, i have tried your code and now its working as i wanted.thank you

Comment: Glad to have been able to help you. If my solution, my answer helped you, you can vote for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get "1" when checked and "0" when unchecked.
The HTML and PHP code below should be able to help you

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="my_page.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="myCase"    id="myCase" value="1"><label for="myCase">My Case</label>
</form>
```

And "my_page.php" code

```
$myCase = (isset($_POST["myCase"]))?$_POST["myCase"]:"0";

echo "<br />myCase : ".$myCase;
```